# how to LEFT JOIN a table, take the SUM() or return 0 with a WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, where-clause

Take the following data:

```
db.users

id      name
1       David
2       James
3       Mary

db.payments
amount  user_id     paid
5       1           0
55      1           1
94      1           1
5       2           0
55      2           1
94      2           1
5       2           0
55      2           1
94      2           1
```

I'd like to LEFT JOIN the payments table to the users table and SUM() the amount where paid = 0:

```
SELECT users.*, SUM(payments.amount)
FROM users
LEFT JOIN payments
ON users.id = payments.user_id
WHERE payments.paid = 0
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY users.id DESC
```

The problem arises in that 'mary' (user 3) doesn't get returned because she doesn't have any records in the payments table. This is down to the WHERE clause checking for paid = 0.

I'd like it to return 0 as the sum if no records.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move predicate `payments.paid = 0` from `WHERE` to `ON` clause, like:

```
SELECT users.*, SUM(payments.amount)
FROM users
LEFT JOIN payments
ON users.id = payments.user_id AND payments.paid = 0
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY users.id DESC
```

If you place the predicate in the `WHERE` clause `LEFT JOIN` becomes an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick...not sure why I didn't think of that :P. Now I just need to work on optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put-> sum(isnull(payment.amount,0)) as Payment count in your query

```
SELECT users.*, SUM(isnull(payments.amount,0))
FROM users
LEFT JOIN payments
ON users.id = payments.user_id
WHERE payments.paid = 0
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY users.id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
SELECT users.Id, users.name, SUM(case when paid=0 then amount else 0 end) as 
req_amt
FROM users
LEFT JOIN payments
ON users.id = payments.user_id
GROUP BY users.id,users.name
ORDER BY users.id DESC
```

Thanks:-)